# Como usar la variable de un metodo en otro metodo?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Quiero usar las variables latitude y longitude previamente asignadas en el método onLocationChanged(Location location) y usarlas en el método Method()

Método de donde quiero sacar latitud y longitud

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    Log.d("onLocationChanged", "entered");

    mLastLocation = location;
    if (mCurrLocationMarker != null) {
        mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
    }

    //Place current location marker
    latitude = location.getLatitude();//aqui estamos obteniendo la latitud
    longitude = location.getLongitude();//aqui estamos obteniendo la longitud
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    markerOptions.position(latLng);
    markerOptions.title("Current Position");
    markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));//esto define el color del marcador
    mCurrLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);//esto añade un marcador en nuestra posocion

    //move map camera
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));
    Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this,"Your Current Location", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    Log.d("onLocationChanged", String.format("latitude:%.3f longitude:%.3f",latitude,longitude));

    //stop location updates
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, (com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener) this);// LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
        Log.d("onLocationChanged", "Removing Location Updates");
    }
    Log.d("onLocationChanged", "Exit");

}
```

Método donde las quiero usar

```
 public void Method(){
        String Restaurant = "restaurant";
                //mMap.clear();
                String url = getUrl(latitude, longitude, Restaurant);
                Object[] DataTransfer = new Object[2];
                DataTransfer[0] = mMap;
                DataTransfer[1] = url;
                Log.d("onClick", url);
                GetNearbyPlacesData getNearbyPlacesData = new GetNearbyPlacesData();
                getNearbyPlacesData.execute(DataTransfer);
                Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this,"Nearby Restaurants", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Comment: Podrias retornar los valores y pasarlos como parametros.

Comment: No me funciona, el metodo no deja retornar nada y no se puede cambiar que se void pues es generado por los servicios de google play

Comment: Has pensado en declarar una variable global Location? Le puedes asignar un valor al entrar al método onLocationChanged y utilizarlo luego en el método Method.

Answer (score 1):

si estás dentro de una clase, lo mas conveniente sería declarar las propiedades latitud y longitude como miembros de la clase

```
public class Myclass{

        public latitude;
        public longitude;

        @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {...}

        public void Method(){...}

        }
```

luego les asignas un valor en el evento onLocationChanged()

```
   //Nótese el uso de 'THIS' para acceder a las propiedades de la clase

    this.latitude = location.getLatitude();//aqui estamos obteniendo la latitud
    this.longitude = location.getLongitude();//aqui estamos obteniendo la longitud
```

y por último, accedes en tu método a éstas mismas propiedades

```
 public void Method(){
        String Restaurant = "restaurant";
                //mMap.clear();
                String url = getUrl(this.latitude, this.longitude, Restaurant);
                Object[] DataTransfer = new Object[2];
                DataTransfer[0] = mMap;
                DataTransfer[1] = url;
                Log.d("onClick", url);
                GetNearbyPlacesData getNearbyPlacesData = new GetNearbyPlacesData();
                getNearbyPlacesData.execute(DataTransfer);
                Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this,"Nearby Restaurants", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

en tu method dile que va a recibir variables

```
public void Method(double lat, double lon){
    String Restaurant = "restaurant";
    String url = getUrl(lat, lon, Restaurant);
    ......mode code
}
```

y simplemente donde vallas a llamar tu `Method` pasas los datos de la siguiente forma `Method(latitude,longitude);` pero claro previamente las variables `latitude y longitude` deben ir al inicio para que se usen en toda la `clase`